# Running a python code with php

Tags: php, python

I have a python script which is needed to be run by php:

```
     <?php
     $command = escapeshellcmd('/home/Desktop/test.py');
     $output = shell_exec($command);
     echo $output;

     ?>
```

The out put of the python script is a binary file but I get the following error in the log:
            Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?

The php code works fine from the terminal but no luck when I try to run it from the browser. Any idea what is going on? Ideally, I don't want to change my program. I want to know how you can rectify the X Display error. Is there a way to check if  $DISPLAY is set properly? ( I am working with Ubuntu)

I tried this : pidof X && echo "yup X server is running" on my terminal and it is saying yup x server is running!

Comment: Sounds like `$DISPLAY` isn't set. Why are you trying to run a GUI app from a webserver?

Comment: `echo` prints out strings, si `shell_exec` should return a string. I think that you have to modify your [tag:python] script to return only string and it should not use any GUI.

Comment: Your app uses something that uses the X server.

The terminal user probably has the X server running, so it works. The PHP running user does not have the X server running, so it doesn't work.

My suggestion would be to modify the script to not use any X requiring methods or start X and access it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following text as the first line of your Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Without this, the kernel doesn't know what interpreter to run your script with, and may end up trying to launch it using `/usr/bin/import` (because that word probably appears on the first line of the script). The `import` utility requires access to the X11 display (it's a screenshot utility, basically), which is why you're getting this error.

Comment: What about if the server is Windows?

Comment: @sємsєм If they're using something like Cygwin, it'll work! If not, we'd need to know a lot more about their configuration.

Comment: This is my first line of python script:  #!/usr/bin/env python so should I change it to #!/usr/bin/python ?

Comment: Hmm, no, that should be fine then. Can you answer some of the comments on your post asking what your script is doing?

Comment: The output is saved in a C++ format ....self.blocks_file_meta_sink_0 = blocks.file_meta_sink( blocks.GR_FILE_FLOAT, True, int(header_every*250), self.extras_str, True)..It reads the data from another device

Answer (score 0):

The python file you need may need to open a window to run. You say you saw it run in terminal though? What's test.py? Is it propitiatory? 
If you try using this as a command in your PHP: (not 100% that the shell escape won't strip this so may need to comment that out)

```
python -c \'print \"Test\"\'
```

and see if you get the output text back. If so it's a python issue not PHP and the test.py file may be instantiating something that needs the $DISPLAY var set. PHP doesn't set the $DISPLAY var as it is shell commands not GUI.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by asking "Is it propitiatory?"..the program reads the data from a receiver.

Answer (score 0):

try `popen`

```
$command = "/usr/bin/python /home/Desktop/test.py";
$handle = popen($command, "r");
```

"r" for read

```
$read = fread($handle, 10);
```

10 is the size of output you want to take,

```
echo $read ;
```

hope it helps,

Comment: This won't solve the problem. (In fact, it won't work at all, because the path to python is missing a slash.)

Comment: sorry that was a typo mistake,